# Strangely worded question involving hypergeometric distribution calculation

Tags: probability-theory

Here's the question that I can't make heads or tails of:

"In the 2012 contest for the president of the United States, based on the winning margin
in Montana which has 861 precincts, it is known that miscounts in 65 or more precincts
(assuming at most 20% votes could be miscounted in a precinct) will overturn the winner
of the election in Montana. An election result in the state is to be judged incorrect if one
or more of the sampled precincts are miscounted. Determine the number of precincts
that should be audited to guarantee the probability of not detecting an incorrect election
is at most 0.05?"

I believe this is a hypergeometric distribution, where we let

X = number of miscounted precincts in a sample

N = 861: the total number of precincts

M = 65: the minimum number of miscounts for a incorrect election

K = what we are trying to find

So, this is what I've interpreted from the question. We are interested in the value of $K$ when $P(X = 0)=0.05$, since $P(X=0)$ represents not detecting the incorrect election, since $P(X\ge1)$ judges an incorrect election.

So, $P(X=0)=0.05 = \frac{{65\choose0}{(861-65)\choose K}}{861\choose K}=\frac{{65\choose0}{796\choose K}}{861\choose K}$

Not sure if this is correct. If it is, I don't know how to solve for K from here.

Comment: It is called hypergeometric, not negative binomial

Comment: Whoops, you're 100% right, I mixed it up with something else. It should be hypergeometric.

Comment: Hm, it seems correct, but it is indeed not so easy to find K from the last equation. Are you allowed to do some trial and error in Excel or something?

Comment: Unfortunately no...that's why I think I'm doing something wrong with regards to the question itself. I know the expected value of X for hypergeometric is $\frac{KM}N$, so I wonder if I could do anything with that.